# Getting Id as selected text in Vuetify's v-select in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using v-select in Vue.js and using it like this:

```
 <v-select :options="items" v-model="Form.id" @input="setSelected($event)"></v-select>
```

but it is showing id as selected text i want to show its value as its text.

Presently i'm getting output like this image:

[image]

> Data Fromat:

```
   [
    {
    "id":1,
    "label":"laptop",
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "label":"mouse",
    },
    {
    "id":3,
    "label":"PC",
    }
    ]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How does your data look like?

Comment: @MoDGenesis: I have added format in my question, https://codepen.io/RoxxE/pen/pobNObw i want to set option with default id 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the `item-text` prop with `label` :

```
<v-select :options="items" item-text="label" item-value="id" v-model="Form"
 return-object
 @input="setSelected($event)">
</v-select>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/MWebXNW)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried your code but it is still showing id as selected text, I have also added data format. Please check, i'm using options also with item-text and items

Comment: Can u please check this link https://codepen.io/RoxxE/pen/pobNObw. I'm trying to set id 2 as default value and display Bar

Comment: in your case change it to `item-text="label"`

Comment: Can u please check this link https://codepen.io/RoxxE/pen/pobNObw

Comment: bind your `v-model` to an object like `v-model="selected"` and `return-object`

Comment: I have already done it in this link but it is not selecting id 2 on load

Comment: please check this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/dyXOgBz

Comment: Thanks, This was what i wanted

Comment: I can't get any values from these menus. Even $event is undefined. Anyone else have similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-select :items="items" item-text="label" label="Standard"></v-select>
```

It's almost the same as above but this is what you are exactly looking for.

The item-text = "label" is because your data type has id, **label**

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the value of v-modal you can parse that value to integer

this.form = parseInt(this.form);

It's working for me

Thank you.